# Question on series and integral. Given $I_n = \frac{2}{n+2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

I have taken only the part that I do not understand to ask for help here.

Given $I_n = \frac{2}{n+2}$

Hence, $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} (I_{n-1}+I_{n}+I_{n+1}+\cdots+I_{2n-2}) = \int_0^\fbox{A} \frac{\fbox{B}}{\fbox{C}+x} dx $

My question is how to solve for the letters in those three boxes.

Reference to the knowledge that used to solve this question would be helpful.

Thanks you.

For more information, the book has answers
$A=1, B=2, C=1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$S=\lim_{n \to \infty} (I_{n-1}+I_{n}+I_{n+1}+\ldots+I_{2n-2}) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n-1}^{2n-2}I_k=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n-1}^{2n-2}\frac{2}{k+2}\\=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{2}{k}$$
Now:
$$S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{2}{(k/n)}=\int_{\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)/n}^{\lim_{n\to\infty}(2n)/n}\frac2x{\rm d}x=\int_1^2\frac2x{\rm d}x\stackrel{x\to x-1}=\int_0^1\frac2{x+1}{\rm d}x$$

Answer (score -1):

This is Riemann sums: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}$. Do check the algebra though!

Answer (score -1):

Since $$\int \limits_a^{a+s} f(x) \, \text{d} x = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{s}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f \left( a + \frac{k}{n} \cdot s \right),$$
you typically need to pull out the factor $\frac{1}{n}$ before the sum and try to interpret the rest as the other part. So:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} I_{n-1} + \ldots + I_{2n-2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2}{n+1} + \ldots + \frac{2}{2n} = \frac{1}{n} \left[ \frac{2}{1+\frac{1}{n}} + \frac{2}{1+\frac{2}{n}} + \ldots + \frac{2}{1+\frac{n}{n}} \right]. $$
Now if you search for a function $f$ and number $s$ such that
$$\frac{2}{1+\frac{k}{n}} = s \cdot f \left( 0 + \frac{k}{n} \cdot s \right),$$
surely you will notice that $f(x) = \frac{2}{1+x}$ and $s = 1$ fit, which lets us conclude that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \left[ \frac{2}{1+\frac{1}{n}} + \frac{2}{1+\frac{2}{n}} + \ldots + \frac{2}{1+\frac{n}{n}} \right] = \int \limits_0^1 \frac{2}{1+x} \, \text{d} x.$$